Too many levels of symbolic links for many standard executables
I don't understand the "xargs: echo: Too many levels of symbolic links" I'm getting in the new Ubuntu 24.04 LTS:
UPDATE 3: It turns out to be something wrong with my PATH variable. Thought the circular symlink is somewhere in my file system but it's actually from my PATH variable. Someone close this please.
$ seq 3 | xargs
xargs: echo: Too many levels of symbolic links

$ type xargs
xargs is hashed (/usr/bin/xargs)

$ file /usr/bin/xargs
/usr/bin/xargs: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=79b7a3c07c6fe7414c813f0896c26cc0e1c3d61e, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin

$ which echo
/usr/bin/echo

$ ls -l /usr/bin/echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35208 2024-04-05 10:36 /usr/bin/echo

$ file /usr/bin/echo
/usr/bin/echo: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=0a5ded42f3646eeb3cc2f6bed66db79e5dfa3dc9, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

UPDATE:
$ seq 3 | xargs /usr/bin/echo
1 2 3

$ seq 3 | xargs echo
xargs: echo: Too many levels of symbolic links

$ type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash

$ file /usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=2f77b36371c214e11670c7d9d92727e9a49f626b, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /usr/bin/echo
echo is /bin/echo

$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3

$ /usr/bin/echo 1 2 3
1 2 3

And I just found more such "Too many levels of symbolic links" errors with tar:
cd /tmp
mkdir t
cd t
echo a | tee a b c

$ tar -cvzf ../t.tgz .
./
./a
./b
./c

$ tar tvf ../t.tgz
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: Too many levels of symbolic links
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ type tar
tar is hashed (/usr/bin/tar)

$ type gzip
gzip is /usr/bin/gzip

$ file /usr/bin/tar
/usr/bin/tar: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b215a0463ea0544382954531f8291bcb577b97aa, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ file /usr/bin/gzip
/usr/bin/gzip: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=64c813330cadb446347614e4caca345af0016708, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ ls -l / | grep bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 2024-04-22 09:08 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2024-02-26 07:58 bin.usr-is-merged
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 2024-04-22 09:08 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2024-03-31 05:00 sbin.usr-is-merged

$ ls -ld /usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 36864 2024-07-29 15:27 /usr/bin


UPDATE 2:
More such "Too many levels of symbolic links" errors:
$ dpkg -l | head
dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): Too many levels of symbolic links

$ type dpkg
dpkg is /usr/bin/dpkg

$ type dpkg-query
dpkg-query is /usr/bin/dpkg-query

$ file /usr/bin/dpkg
/usr/bin/dpkg: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=221db25314785a7426e131a493758cc3dfc6c44b, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ file /usr/bin/dpkg-query
/usr/bin/dpkg-query: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b6164d9fee278cad7dc2977cd924a54ab7485ab7, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

It's been working fine in older releases.
What's the fix please?

Hmm... so what happens if you do seq 3 | xargs /usr/bin/echo explicitly?

BINGO! @steeldriver, but what's the fix? See my update OP -- there're more problems.

Take a look at your filesystem.  You probably have a circular set of links for /bin,  /usr/bin -- They are not separate directories like  they used to be, /bin now should be a link to /usr/bin, with /usr/bin the real directory.

Add the output of type -a echo, please

@muru added in the output of update.

@ubfan1, have you checked my diagnostic output at end of of update, before update 2?

It does work in 24.04. seq 3 | xargs returns 1 2 3 Take a look at your filesystem as others suggested.

It turns out to be something wrong with my PATH. The circular symlink is from there. Some one close this please.

It turns out to be something wrong with my PATH variable. Thought the circular symlink is somewhere in my file system but it's actually from my PATH variable, that is beyond all reported places in OP --
A circular symlink path exists in my PATH.

Can you show us the code for the circular symlink path that exists in your PATH?

Part of a path that exist in my PATH has circular symlink @karel -- A simplest example: a path in my PATH: /pkg/bin, part of it has circular symlink, like: /pkg -> /pkg.
